# Echoing progress from a background process without hijacking prompt

Tags: bash, shell, prompt, background-process

Consider the simple script `hello`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'hello world!'
```

Now from bash if I try to run this in the background:

```
$ hello &
[1] 12345
$ hello world!
█ <--- prompt is stuck here until I hit enter!
[1]+ Done
$ █ <--- prompt back to normal
```

What I would rather see:

```
$ hello &
[1] 12345
[1]+ hello world!
[1]+ Done
$ █ <--- prompt normal the whole time
```

How can I change the behavior?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a matter of timing: bash launches the `hello` command in the background, then it displays a prompt to let you enter a new command, then the background command prints some output. When you enter the next command line (an empty command line, if you just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>), bash displays the notification that the background job has finished, then the next prompt.

You may want to experiment with a script that starts with `sleep 3` and start typing just after launching the script in the background, to see what's happening at a pace you can follow.

You can make bash notify you immediately when a background job terminates by setting the `notify` option with [`set -b`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-set). Then you'll see:

```
$ set -b
$ hello &
[1] 12345
$ hello world!
[1]+ Done
```

Bash doesn't redraw the prompt in this case. You're still editing a command line on the prompt line that appeared before the background job printed `hello world!`. You can redraw the current line by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>. You may want to bind the command `redraw-current-line` to a more convenient key; for example, to have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> redraw the current line and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> clear the screen, add the following lines to your `~/.inputrc`:

```
"\C-l": redraw-current-line
"\e\C-l": clear-screen
```

I don't know of a way to make bash redraw the prompt line automatically. Zsh does it by default.